# Select an particular node (with colon) from xml file and bind it in model class

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, xml-namespaces, selectnodes

I need to read an xml file tag which has colon in it and bind it into model class

My xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xml:base=""
    xmlns=""
    xmlns:d=""
    xmlns:m="">
    <id>my url</id>
    <title type="text">ItemList</title>
    <updated>2019-05-07T14:18:08Z</updated>
    <link rel="self" title="ItemList" href="ItemList" />
    <entry m:etag="">
        <id></id>
        <category term="NAV.ItemList" scheme="" />
        <link rel="edit" title="ItemList" href="" />
        <title />
        <updated>2019-05-07T14:18:08Z</updated>
        <author>
            <name />
        </author>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:No>LSU-458</d:No>
                <d:Description>speaker</d:Description>
                <d:Type>Inventory</d:Type>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

My c# code

```
 List<CustomerModel> customers = new List<CustomerModel>();
 doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/oWtMRUR8_.xml"));
 foreach (XmlNode node in 
 doc.SelectNodes("/feed/id/title/updated/link/mproperties"))
 {
    customers.Add(new CustomerModel
    {
        No = int.Parse(node["d:No"].InnerText),
        Description = node["d:Description"].InnerText,
        Type = node["d:Type"].InnerText
    });
 }
 return View(customers);
```

I need to bind only the d:no,d:description,d:type in my model class using foreach loop,these tags are with colon so I am not able to extract the contents in the tag and namespace was mentioned as an option(but didn't worked). I am new to this and can't able to find the right method, hope anyone helps.

My expected result:

```
                No =LSU-458 ,
                Description = speaker,
                Type  = Inventory
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the XML is not valid, the namespace declarations need a name, for example

```
<feed xml:base="""" xmlns="""" xmlns:d=""d"" xmlns:m=""m"">
```

Then you can loop through the `properties` like this:

```
var root = doc.SelectSingleNode("/feed/entry/content");
foreach (XmlNode node in root.ChildNodes)
{
    customers.Add(new CustomerModel
    {
        No = node["d:No"].InnerText,
        Description = node["d:Description"].InnerText,
        Type = node["d:Type"].InnerText
    });
}
```

And finally, you cannot `int.Parse()` the `d:No` because it's a string.

Comment: The xml is valid only I have removed the url's in the feed and id tag as I am not allowed to post it public @iakobski

Comment: OK, that's fine. Using the dummy namespace as above made it parse so I could run the example.

Comment: but how to include m:properties in the selectsinglenode and pass d:no in model

Comment: You can't without XSLT, but you can select the ChildNodes, and you can access the Node d:No

Comment: `"/feed/id/title/updated/link"` is not a valid path in the XML, they are child nodes of `feed` not each other, i.e. they are `/feed/id` `/feed/title` and so on.

Comment: @lakobski I tried your code,but it throws error while executing the( var root = doc.SelectSingleNode("/feed/id/title/updated/link/entry/id/category/link/title/updated/author/name/content/m:properties"); ) . the error is :  An exception of type 'System.Xml.XPath.XPathException' occurred in System.Xml.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.

Comment: if I try with " var root = doc.SelectSingleNode("/feed/entry/content"); " ,it is coming as object reference not set to an instance of object @lakobski

Comment: Yes, that's what I said, you can't `SelectSingleNode` or `SelectNodes` on anything with a namespace resolution (m:properties) without XsltContext. But in any case your path does not resolve to anything in your sample - `/feed/id/title` does not exist. I ran the code against the sample you posted and `/feed/entry/content` does resolve to a node, so I can only assume the sample is not the same as what you actually have.

Comment: Ok , and I am fine with using the XsltContext,I just want to get the job done,do you have any idea of using XsltContext and binding it in model.I have the same xml code and the only thing which I have altered here is only this code(<feed xml:base="""" xmlns="""" xmlns:d=""d"" xmlns:m=""m"">),I have got stuck in this for past couple of days,any solution to this will be very needful @iakobski

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193256/discussion-between-gokul-and-iakobski).

Answer (score 0):

Hi all I got the answer and I am posting it, hope it might help someone in future:

```
XmlNamespaceManager namespaces = new
XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
namespaces.AddNamespace("m", "our_url_link");
XmlNodeList nodemsg = doc.SelectNodes("//m:properties", namespaces);
foreach (XmlNode xnz in nodemsg)
{
    customers.Add(new CustomerModel
    {
        //item.Element("d:No").Value
        No = xnz["d:No"].InnerText,
        Description = xnz["d:Description"].InnerText,
        Type = xnz["d:Type"].InnerText
    });
}
```